# Outlook Web Addins not show in some Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-addins

I found some Outlook 2016 cannot show my addins after I upgrade my Exchange Server 2016 to CU4. The vesion number of these Outlook 2016 are 16.0.4266.1003,  both x86 and x64 version. Other versions of Outlook 2016 can show my icon normally.

Then I deployed my manifest file in O365 ecp and connect O365 with these Outlook 2016, still Outlook 2016 of version 16.0.4266.1003 cannot show my addins, while other Outlook 2016 works fine.

Here is my manifest file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" 
xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Identification -->
  <Id>3074fd59-6028-400b-a2e0-39f68eba694c</Id>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>MSUCPLUS</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>zh-CN</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="ExDrivePlus" />
  <Description DefaultValue="免插件安装且兼容多Outlook版本的邮件大附件分享体验" />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/icon_64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/icon_128.png" />
  
  <!-- Support -->
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://www.msucplus.com" />
  
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <!-- Old schema. This will be overridden by the VersionOverrides below. -->
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/" />
      </DesktopSettings>
      
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <!-- /Old schema. -->

  <!-- VersionOverrides1.0-->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Description resid="residAppDescription" />

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
  
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgComposeTabMessage.grp1">
                <Label resid="residAppName" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskPane0BtnCompose">
                  <Label resid="residTaskPaneButton0Name" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="residTaskPaneButton0Name" />
                    <Description resid="residComposeSupertip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="tp16icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="tp32icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="tp80icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="residTaskpaneComposeUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="apptComposeTabMessage.grp1">
                <Label resid="residAppName" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="appTaskPane0BtnCompose">
                  <Label resid="residTaskPaneButton0Name" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="residTaskPaneButton0Name" />
                    <Description resid="residComposeSupertip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="tp16icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="tp32icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="tp80icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="residTaskpaneComposeUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
 
 <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="tp16icon" DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/icon_16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="tp32icon" DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/icon_32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="tp80icon" DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/icon_80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      
   <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="residTaskpaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/" />
        <bt:Url id="residTaskpaneComposeUrl" DefaultValue="https://sps.lyncmp.com/o/" />
      </bt:Urls>
      
   <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="residTaskPaneButton0Name" DefaultValue="邮件大附件">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residAppName" DefaultValue="ExDrivePlus(Trial)">
        </bt:String>
      </bt:ShortStrings>

      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="residAppDescription" DefaultValue="ExDrivePlus(Trial)">
        </bt:String>
        <bt:String id="residComposeSupertip" DefaultValue="点击这里开始分享大附件">
        </bt:String>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
 <!-- /VersionOverrides1.0-->
  

  
  </VersionOverrides>
  
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: What versions of Outlook DO show your add-in?
What versions of Exchange Show your add-in?

Comment: I tested your manifest on an Outlook 16.0.45XX. (MSI) version and also Outlook 16.0.8030.1000 (C2R) and it worked fine. You may want to get the latest patches to make sure everything is ok. However, it may be due to the exchange server, so getting that version may help diagnose the problem.